# Using SelectFirst with a condition that relies on the input

Tags: list, search, wolfram-mathematica, conditional-statements

I'm trying to find the first instance in a list, a, for which the element is not a member of another list, b. I'm thinking to use something similar to this:

```
a = {r,j,k};
b = {r,m,n};
firstnonmatch = SelectFirst[a,MemberQ[b,a_i]==False]
```

where firstnonmatch would return m. But I'm not sure how to refer to elements of the list in the conditions when using SelectFirst[]. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: is that python?

Answer (score 0):

the *crit* argument needs to be a function, here you use a *pure function*:

```
 a = {r,j,k};
 b = {r,m,n};
 SelectFirst[a,!MemberQ[b,#]&]
```

> j